# Check box checked attribute showing different value in Firefox and chrome in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox

My checkbox is below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" onclick="chkAll()"  />
```

Javascript Code

```
    function chkAll() {
            var chkBox = document.getElementById('checkAll');

            alert(chkBox.checked);
}
```

The alert is showing true in firefox and false in chrome.

Please anybody can give a solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: worked fine in my firefox as well as chrome Browser

Comment: Works fine, here i made a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/lecudabiju/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your try.. Might be I am using this checkbox inside Kendo UI Grid Control.